# Devise's registration_path, how it's generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Default Devise user signup form looks like this:

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

When I run `rake routes` I don't see any `registration` prefix, there is `user_registration`, `new_user_registration` etc. but not just `registration`, so how does it work? Where can I find it's source code?

Answer (score 2):

The registration_path route is generated in 
[Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb).

As you can see in the code below it just calls your regular routes.

```rb
def self.generate_helpers!(routes=nil)
  routes ||= begin
    mappings = Devise.mappings.values.map(&:used_helpers).flatten.uniq
    Devise::URL_HELPERS.slice(*mappings)
  end

  routes.each do |module_name, actions|
    [:path, :url].each do |path_or_url|
      actions.each do |action|
        action = action ? "#{action}_" : ""
        method = "#{action}#{module_name}_#{path_or_url}"

        class_eval <<-URL_HELPERS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def #{method}(resource_or_scope, *args)
            scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
            _devise_route_context.send("#{action}\#{scope}_#{module_name}_#{path_or_url}", *args)
          end
        URL_HELPERS
      end
    end
  end
end

generate_helpers!(Devise::URL_HELPERS)
```

With `Devise::URL_HELPERS` being:

```
{:session=>[nil, :new, :destroy], :omniauth_callback=>[], :password=>[nil, :new, :edit], :registration=>[nil, :new, :edit, :cancel], :confirmation=>[nil, :new], :unlock=>[nil, :new]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your `routes.rb`

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations',
                                      :passwords => 'devise/passwords'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

And then run rake routes. You can find the devise controller at: [List of Devise Controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise)

Comment: I know, but where can I find this `registration_path(resource_name)` definition?

Comment: Take a read of this: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method, this is automatically defined for you when you include this method.